# How can I get the same object in the visitor area as I get in the admin area without the user $uid

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

Currently on a blog website like I got a problem I didn't expect when I start building it...

I build it like this:

• A admin area where you have to login where you can write/delete articles.

• A public area where you don't need to login where you can see the articles write in the admin area.

My database is build like below as you can see every user got a $uid. So because of how it's build my service look like this:

```
{
  "articles" : {
    "xgbKhFzeY1XvIlluGItaBPAvwQQ2" : {
      "-LORxrYnctixsx5sQ5DM" : {
        "author" : "Zinedine Zidane",
        "categories" : [ "Football", "Tennis" ],
        "content" : "<p>Constituendi autem sunt qui sint in amicitia fines et quasi termini diligendi. De quibus tres video sententias ferri, quarum nullam probo, unam, ut eodem modo erga amicum adfecti simus, quo erga nosmet ipsos, alteram, ut nostra in amicos benevolentia illorum erga nos benevolentiae pariter aequaliterque respondeat, tertiam, ut, quanti quisque se ipse facit, tanti fiat ab amicis.Constituendi autem sunt qui sint in amicitia fines et quasi termini diligendi. De quibus tres video sententias ferri, quarum nullam probo, unam, ut eodem modo erga amicum adfecti simus, quo erga nosmet ipsos, alteram, ut nostra in amicos benevolentia illorum erga nos benevolentiae pariter aequaliterque respondeat, tertiam, ut, quanti quisque se ipse facit, tanti fiat ab amicis.</p>",
        "date" : 1539158014424,
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/csbj-handisport-38.appspot.com/o/41666967_311898482736538_5532086598150712503_n.jpg?alt=media&token=6b13fe37-357e-45db-8d0e-4436e166d359",
        "name" : "Thalassio otium quem et hortaretur. \t"
      },
      "-LORy85GKdT9U9p_Iolk" : {
        "author" : "David Kidouille",
        "categories" : [ "Football", "ChatMignon" ],
        "content" : "<p>Ego vero sic intellego, Patres conscripti, nos hoc tempore in provinciis decernendis perpetuae pacis habere oportere rationem. Nam quis hoc non sentit omnia alia esse nobis vacua ab omni periculo atque etiam suspicione belli?Ego vero sic intellego, Patres conscripti, nos hoc tempore in provinciis decernendis perpetuae pacis habere oportere rationem. Nam quis hoc non sentit omnia alia esse nobis vacua ab omni periculo atque etiam suspicione belli?</p>",
        "date" : 1539158086263,
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/csbj-handisport-38.appspot.com/o/36981961_1869531810009121_4498273348232413184_n.jpg?alt=media&token=47fc2e67-d198-4533-8939-abc5d3dbed51",
        "name" : "Omni habere atque perpetuae sic."
      },
      "-LOTQNaI7ry3WRavCjNt" : {
        "author" : "Sophia Green",
        "categories" : [ "Espresso", "Title" ],
        "content" : "<p>Harum trium sententiarum nulli prorsus assentior. Nec enim illa prima vera est, ut, quem ad modum in se quisque sit, sic in amicum sit animatus. Quam multa enim, quae nostra causa numquam faceremus, facimus causa amicorum! precari ab indigno, supplicare, tum acerbius in aliquem invehi insectarique vehementius, quae in nostris rebus non satis honeste, in amicorum fiunt honestissime; multaeque res sunt in quibus de suis commodis viri boni multa detrahunt detrahique patiuntur, ut iis amici potius quam ipsi fruantur.</p><p>Ibi victu recreati et quiete, postquam abierat timor, vicos opulentos adorti equestrium adventu cohortium, quae casu propinquabant, nec resistere planitie porrecta conati digressi sunt retroque concedentes omne iuventutis robur relictum in sedibus acciverunt.</p><p>Non ergo erunt homines deliciis diffluentes audiendi, si quando de amicitia, quam nec usu nec ratione habent cognitam, disputabunt. Nam quis est, pro deorum fidem atque hominum! qui velit, ut neque diligat quemquam nec ipse ab ullo diligatur, circumfluere omnibus copiis atque in omnium rerum abundantia vivere? Haec enim est tyrannorum vita nimirum, in qua nulla fides, nulla caritas, nulla stabilis benevolentiae potest esse fiducia, omnia semper suspecta atque sollicita, nullus locus amicitiae.</p>",
        "date" : 1539182528987,
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/csbj-handisport-38.appspot.com/o/37112713_499156913858390_6321776699583234048_n.jpg?alt=media&token=dea02d84-dcc8-427e-92d1-92529499e052",
        "name" : "Plerisque honoribus inventu in verae descendant quas in graves enim"
      }
    }
  },
  "contact" : {
    "xgbKhFzeY1XvIlluGItaBPAvwQQ2" : {
      "adress" : "Bla Bla Bla",
      "email" : "michel@gmail.com",
      "facebook" : "www.facebook.com",
      "phone" : "0606060606"
    }
  },
  "evenements" : {
    "xgbKhFzeY1XvIlluGItaBPAvwQQ2" : {
      "-LORx0d49L5W1OHbaPkz" : {
        "content" : "<p>Eodem tempore Serenianus ex duce, cuius ignavia populatam in Phoenice Celsen ante rettulimus, pulsatae maiestatis imperii reus iure postulatus ac lege, incertum qua potuit suffragatione absolvi, aperte convictus familiarem suum cum pileo, quo caput operiebat, incantato vetitis artibus ad templum misisse fatidicum, quaeritatum expresse an ei firmum portenderetur imperium, ut cupiebat, et cunctum.</p>",
        "dateEnd" : "20/08/1995",
        "dateStart" : "17/08/1995",
        "name" : "Stand de tir au pigeon",
        "place" : "33 rue de la Liberté, Bourgoin Jallieu"
      }
    }
  },
  "medias" : {
    "xgbKhFzeY1XvIlluGItaBPAvwQQ2" : {
      "-LORymdySlsQ82_rZ6kk" : {
        "description" : "Bla Bla Bla Bla",
        "titre" : "30 ans de michel",
        "type" : "image",
        "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/csbj-handisport-38.appspot.com/o/41466540_333985383837957_6494746608337518152_n.jpg?alt=media&token=079311d7-c42e-4e21-933e-36573e88a893"
      },
      "-LORyzf8ft5hS_MV_B10" : {
        "description" : "klsjbvsjdkbvjkshd",
        "titre" : "Bla Bla bla",
        "type" : "image",
        "url" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/csbj-handisport-38.appspot.com/o/41532985_724838064517122_5880047170186967403_n.jpg?alt=media&token=86632def-47b3-4b30-84c9-c9af571da17d"
      }
    }
  },
  "sports" : {
    "xgbKhFzeY1XvIlluGItaBPAvwQQ2" : {
      "-LORzZ2xq_JszbFaFyyn" : {
        "description" : "<p>Nec vox accusatoris ulla licet subditicii in his malorum quaerebatur acervis ut saltem specie tenus crimina praescriptis legum committerentur, quod aliquotiens fecere principes saevi: sed quicquid Caesaris implacabilitati sedisset, id velut fas iusque perpensum confestim urgebatur impleri.</p>",
        "handisport" : "<p>Ego vero sic intellego, Patres conscripti, nos hoc tempore in provinciis decernendis perpetuae pacis habere oportere rationem. Nam quis hoc non sentit omnia alia esse nobis vacua ab omni periculo atque etiam suspicione belli?</p>",
        "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/csbj-handisport-38.appspot.com/o/42004027_2218122771593693_1511293494740179714_n.jpg?alt=media&token=430ddee9-a818-44ac-b80c-2483be38f1c0",
        "name" : "Football",
        "nbrPlayer" : 10,
        "partTime" : 30
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Service in the Admin Area where I can access the $uid

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { filter, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { Store } from '../../store';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

export interface Article {
    name: string,
    author: string,
    categories: string[],
    content: string,
    date: string,
    image: string,
    key: string,
    $exists: () => boolean
  }

@Injectable()
export class ArticlesService {


    articles$ = this.db.list<Article>(`articles/${this.uid}`).snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(map(actions => 
            actions.map(a => ({ key: a.key, ...a.payload.val() }))
        ))
        .pipe(tap(next => {
            this.store.set('articles', next);
        })
    );

    constructor(
        private store: Store,
        private db: AngularFireDatabase,
        private authService: AuthService
    ) {}

    get uid() {
        return this.authService.user.uid;
    }

    getArticle(key: string) {
        if (!key) return of({});
        return this.store.select<Article[]>(`articles`)
            .pipe(filter(Boolean))
            .pipe(map(articles => articles.find((article: Article) => article.key === key)));
    }

    addArticle(article: Article) {
        return this.db.list(`articles/${this.uid}`).push(article);
    }

    updateArticle(key: string, article: Article) {
        return this.db.object(`articles/${this.uid}/${key}`).update(article);
    }

    removeArticle(key: string) {
        return this.db.list(`articles/${this.uid}`).remove(key);
    }

}
```

My Service in the Admin Area where I can't access the $uid

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { filter, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { Store } from '../../store';



export interface Article {
    name: string,
    author: string,
    category: string[],
    content: string,
    date: string,
    image: string,
    key: string,
    $exists: () => boolean
  }

@Injectable()
export class ArticlesService {


    articles$ = this.db.list<Article>(`articles`).snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(map(userId =>   
            userId.map(a => ({ ...a.payload.val() }))
        )).pipe(tap(next => {
            this.store.set('articles', next);
        }));

    constructor(
        private store: Store,
        private db: AngularFireDatabase
    ) {}

        getArticle(key: string) {
            if (!key) return of({});
            return this.store.select<Article[]>(`articles`)
                .pipe(filter(Boolean))
                .pipe(map(articles => articles.find((article: Article) => article.key === key)));
        }

}
```

So When I call the service for get my articles in the admin area I [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNqAm.png) and in the public area I [get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqEBh.png).

I find a way to get the value but with this way I lose the key object.

```
export interface Article {
    name: string,
    author: string,
    category: string[],
    content: string,
    date: string,
    image: string,
    key: string,
    $exists: () => boolean
  }
```

How can I get the same object in the visitor area as I get in the admin area ?

Comment: Please replace all images of text, with the actual text of the images. In the case of the code that should be easy, and you can use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make it looks good. You can get the JSON as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Thanks for the advice this will actually be more readable now !